# jquery with CORS, how to submit jquery with CORS

Tags: jquery, cors

```
jQuery.ajax({                                    
            url: "https://SomeWallet/payment-requests/",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            headers: { "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                        "X-Api-Key": "XXXX",
                       "X-Auth-Token": "XXXX", 
                       "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
                       "Access-Control-Request-Headers":"x-requested-with"
            }, 
            crossDomain: true, 
            data: {
                "some": "sum",
                "buyer_name": "mike",
                "purpose": "iphone7",
                "redirect_url": "https://www.onlineshopping.com",
                "phone": "12345",
                "email": "foo@example.com"
                },
            success: function(data) {                               
                console.info(data);
                }
            });     
    },
```

I am getting below error:

XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://SomeWallet/payment-requests/. Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 401

Comment: 401 means Unauthorized, Forbidden. You may want to confirm your Auth token and Api key.

Comment: The `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header is send by the server (because he defines which origin is allowed to access the send resource) and not by the client.

Comment: Yes, the 401 error means Unauthorized, but if i submit the same request with java client i am not getting the 401 error. So the question is why jquery not taking headers correctly ( FYI, i am not showing the "X-Api-Key" value & "X-Auth-Token" values in above shared code for security concerns ). And also i am making a CORS request. Please help me here